# Is this password generating algorithm vulnerable to brute force attack?

Tags: security, brute-force

I think I have a new way of creating very hard to hack passwords. Assume you have your password, some simple word, like "security" or phrase "cantHackMe". Sure these passwords are easy to bruteforce. So if you left it somewhere and they are only md5 hashed it's easy to crack them with bruteforce, using the dictionary.

If you are thinking a longer password, like 20 letters - oh God it's so hard to remember. What if you had a random password that is easy to remember and you can combine your security with it?

I think I found an easy way to get a random password of any length: just look at your keyboard and think of some algorithm to go through the letters. The simplest way is to go all top row from "q" to "p", next row, from "a" to "l" and next one, from "z" to "b". As the result you will get qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbsecurity. If the attacker is going to use a dictionary, he will doubtless guess, that what figure you decided to use on a keyboard and how many times. And then he'd have to put the dictionary word. Do you see any vulnerabilities in this approach?

I'm not talking about only going keyboard letters one by one from left to right. You can go in any path you are easy to remember. And start and finish at any point. This is an easy way to remember really meaningless sequence of random letters. So you can make something like qazxswedcvfrtgbnhyujmsecurity - it's a sequence of letters pressed from top to bottom. Very easy to remember, hard to bruteforce.

Gumbo pointed out that there's a strategy of cracking passwords, using such paterns like [this](http://www.ijicic.org/ijicic-10-09032.pdf). But as you can see it works only if amount of letters is relatively small and you are not using your password. If it's quite big(more that 20 letters is enough) and you are adding your real password somewhere inside, it's almost unbreakable.

Comment: There are actually dictionaries that contain such keyboard patterns, e.g. [Matt Weir’s keyboard_dic.txt](https://sites.google.com/site/reusablesec/Home/custom-wordlists). Although his dictionary is not that extensive, there is also research on *[Password Cracking based on special Keyboard Patterns](http://www.ijicic.org/ijicic-10-09032.pdf)* which proposes an efficient password cracking system in opposite to brute-forcing.

Comment: Thanks, Gumbo, a very interesting point. But note, that keyboard patterns can be used to crack your password efficiently if it's relatively short and consists only of such patterns. So it seems that if you use kind of long pattern(the whole keyboard once) and your real password it's almost unbreakable.

Comment: @Gumbo updated the question, regarding the link you sent.

Answer (score 1):

What you're considering is similar to the pass phrase, which is a bunch of easy to remember words.  It makes it exponentially more difficult to brute force your password.

However, the state of the art in password protection on the server end is pretty darn good.  Using a modern hash like Blowfish makes it very, very expensive to brute force even relatively short passwords.

Also, simply using different passwords for different systems makes it much less meaningful if someone does crack a system you have an account on, and is probably an easier system to implement for humans.

Comment: Yes, if you are doing all right and people wo are hosting site or making soft are doing all right. It's hard to break. But assuming that there may be a bad hashing algorythm, like md5, or you are using your old password(I know nobody does, especially smart guys like we, but let's imagine this naive person who does). And this is the way to use it and remember.

Comment: Blowfish is a cipher and not hash algorithm. I think you meant bcrypt instead that is a key derivation function that is based on Blowfish.

Answer (score 1):

I see a simple problem in this approach, the keyboard layout may change between keyboards making the method difficult to implement for example when moving from a desktop computer to a laptop, or even a mobile device, making the secuence potentially different...

Comment: I agree. But how much different is it? Most of the letters are at their places all the time. Sure for those who are siwtching between really different keyboards this method is not usefull. But it's a few people.

Comment: It's just something to consider, depending on the characters you want to use (besides letters) like symbols or numbers, and there's also the fact that using a different language setting for the keyboard would also change some characters

Comment: Yes, absolutely! If you are using dvorak and normal keyboards or some gaming keyboard and other ones and they are different - not your way of doing things. Still if you have imagination and can think of a way to go through the letters same for all keyboards - it works. Also note, that some clear to use rule will still make your pssword on any keyboard.

Comment: Makes sense, I guess it's just important to keep those things in mind when using your method, to make sure it works in the most possible keyboards